# Getting next index in Java Integer array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to search an array for an int but it only give the location of the first index it finds if the int appears more than once. For example, if the number 2 appears at index 3 and 7. It will say 3 found at location 3 twice instead of saying 2 found at location 3 and 7. How can I get the additional index of the location where the number also appears.

```
// random_integers is an array of random integers of size 10
Arrays.asList(random_integers);

for (int n : random_integers) {
    if (n == number) {
        System.out.println("Search Value: "
                + number
                + " found at location: "
                + Arrays.asList(random_integers).indexOf(n)
                + " in the unsorted array");
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: `indexOf` method prints first occurrence of object in list , not all. So In one iteration its difficult to get all indexes using arraylist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the behavior of `indexOf`. Instead, use a traditional for loop and just use the current looping variable

```
for (int i = 0; i < random_integers.length; i++){
    if (random_integers[i] == number){
        System.out.println("Search Value: " + number + " found at location: " + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `List#indexOf()` has no idea about your intention to keep last index where item was found recently, so it returns first index every time. You should iterate over array by index, printing it when occurrence found:

```
for (int i; i < random_number.length; i++) {
    if (random_integers[i] == number) {
        System.out.format("Search Value: %s found at location: %s in the unsorted array", number, i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `indexOf()` method returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in the list, or `-1` if the list does not contain the element.

A traditional `for` loop will work here.

```
for(int i=0; i < random_integers.length;i++){
    if (random_integers[i] == number){
        System.out.println("number=" + number + " location=" + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As what all guys said, use traditional `for loop` instead. If you want to use `asList` , try the following code:

```
   int size =  Arrays.asList(a).size();


 for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++){

     if (number == Arrays.asList(a).get(i))
 System.out.println("  Search Value: " + number +
            " found at location: " +        i +
            " in the unsorted array");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code only works, if you are looking to find the current and next index value of a given array, however, if you are looking to find the index of a given value, refer to Michael's answer on this thread.

```
    int totalLength = random_integers.length;

    for (int i=0; i < totalLength; i++){
        int nextIndex = i+1;
        if (nextIndex == totalLength){
            break;
        }else{
           int currentIndexValue = random_integers[i];
           int nextIndexValue = random_integers[nextIndex];
        }
    }
```